# How to create npm package that I can include and run that package in the parent project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm new to node and I created an npm package (https://github.com/toymachiner62/node-mongo-seeds) that I want to be able to include in another project, and then run a script with a parameter in that parent project.

The script from my package that i'm trying to run is `node seed`. I've included this package as a dependency in my main project and when I execute `$ npm seed`, it doesn't work.

```
$ npm seed

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\m089269\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
```

Please help point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you're either trying to do `node seed` or `npm run seed`.

Comment: `node seed` works in my dependency project if i run it as a standalone project. Once i include it in my main project as a dependency, it gives the error I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [npm run-script](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-run-script.html).

In your parent project you should be able to do `npm run-script myDependencyModule seed`. This will execute a script named "seed" defined in myDependencyModule's package.json.

Comment: Is there anyway to shorten that up? Maybe into a custom command or something?

Comment: Well, you could add a script entry to the parent's package.json (e.g. `"depseed": "npm run-script myDependencyModule seed"`). Then you would do `npm run-script depseed` in the parent project directory.

Comment: I'd rather not make the main project have to add something in its package.json to run a script. This project https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-angular-cli has something that allows the user to do `lb-ng ..blah blah` from the parent project. Can you provide some details on how this project shortens the command to a custom one?

Comment: It seems to run successfully, but it doesn't print any of the `console.log` statements to the console. Why not? it does when I run the project as a standalone project.